# Questions about Omniture (SiteCatalyst or Adobe Analytics)

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I am implementing SiteCatalyst for my site and preparing `AppMeasurement.js`.

Within the documentation, I am told that I should paste the following code in the default `AppMeasurement.js`.

```
s = new AppMeasurement()
s.account="my-report-suite"
s.visitorNamespace = "INSERT-NAMESPACE-HERE"

/******** VISITOR ID SERVICE CONFIG - REQUIRES VisitorAPI.js ********/
s.visitor = Visitor.getInstance("INSERT-NAMESPACE-HERE") // same as s.VisitorNamespace

/************************** CONFIG SECTION **************************/
/* You may add or alter any code config here. */
/* Link Tracking Config */
s.trackDownloadLinks=true
s.trackExternalLinks=true
s.trackInlineStats=true
s.linkDownloadFileTypes="exe,zip,wav,mp3,mov,mpg,avi,wmv,pdf,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx"
s.linkInternalFilters="javascript:" //optional: add your internal domain here
s.linkLeaveQueryString=false
s.linkTrackVars="None"
s.linkTrackEvents="None"


s.trackingServer="INSERT-TRACKING-SERVER-HERE"
```

My question is:-

- Should I just copy the above code in `AppMeasurement above the`AppMeasurement()` function?
- Where can I find the `VisitorNameSpace` in my Sitecatalyst Admin?
- How can I find the `trackingServer`?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Found the answer here. [Link to Answer](http://helpx.adobe.com/analytics/using/using-multiple-implementation-types.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I do it works well, but may not be the absolute right way. I believe that the concept for new implementations should use Tag management and thus these would get filled in for you. But I don't have much experience with that area and mostly use the old s_code method. This will also get you the right values for using AppMeasurement.js.

The 3 values you need can be auto-generated in Code Manager.

1. Go to Adobe Marketing Cloud->Reports & Analytics->Admin Tools Select
2. Code Manager from the left-hand menu
3. Under the table is a link to the "legacy code manager" "click here"
4. Leave the defaults except for the Report Suite, which needs to be set the report suite you are targeting.
5. Click "Generate Code", click "Ok" to the warning.
6. Click the tab "Core Javascript File"

This is the legacy s_code file for your Report Suite. It is still the most used option by customers today.

- s_account is your account.
- vistorNamespace and trackingServer are just above the "DO NOT ALTER ..." line and are your other two values.

The code fragment you have above needs to appear at the top of your source for Analytics.

Also look into Tag Management with Adobe, it is the best way forward, and is free. Here are some links:
http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/common-questions-about-dynamic-tag-management/
https://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/dtm/index.html#Deploy_Adobe_Analytics

Comment: umm.. are you still logging into v14? Because v15 no longer "generates" code in the code manager.  There are links to source files, though.. however, those values are no longer genrated. Instead, a generic "[your value here]" type placeholder is there.  The "official" way to get that info now is to contact ClientCare. However, unofficially, if you generate a container in the Tag Manager (NOT dynamic tag manager), you can get the info.

Comment: And on that note.. the regular Tag Manager is going to be discontinued EOY 2014, so you should use DTM -- which does NOT generate that info for you.

Comment: Hi Crayon, I'm using v15 and stand behind what I answered. Please try the procedure I stated. Thanks C

Comment: In regards to Tag Management, I also chose my words carefully. It is the preferred method going forward, and I'm pretty sure the features of the current TM solution will be in DTM when it EOLs. It is tough because implementations in the interim are caught between the old way and a future better way. All we can do is inform and educate.

Comment: Oh you are right, there is indeed a little link at the bottom-right of the page pointing to the legacy code manager

Comment: however, i have been told on both Adobe forums and ClientCare that the "official" way is to now contact ClientCare, and neither mentioned that link, nor my own work-around with TMS.

Comment: Yea, if you are a nominated person to use Client Care that is the best way to go. But the legacy option is still supported and so is getting the values from the Enterprise API if one is comfortable with that. Sometimes you just need to get these things really quickly and that is what I do in those situations. That is why I started my answer with "but may not be the absolute right way." =)