# Are any SiteCatalyst fields required?

Tags: adobe-analytics

Are any of the SiteCatalyst fields required and if so is there documentation which confirms this?

I found this reference for the data insertion fields:

https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/documentation/data-insertion/r-supported-tags

None of them are marked as required or not required.

At some point I thought I read that certain fields were required, but I can't verify that now.

Comment: required for what? And are you implementing via on-page javascript or direct data insertion?

Comment: Simple page view analytics with the JavaScript s code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link (and developer.omniture.com in general) is mostly about server-side implementation and API use.  For the javascript implementation, [go here](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/index.html#Adobe_Analytics_Implementation).

There are several ways to implement javascript tracking. Adobe recommends you implement through the [Dynamic Tag Manager](https://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/dtm/) (DTM), since that's their newest shiniest toy.

Yes, there are a couple of things you must specify. At a minimum:

- report suite id (s_account or s.account) - This is the id generated
  when you create a report suite.
- s.visitorNamespace - You should have gotten this from Adobe when you started a subscription. It's usually the name of your company.
- s.trackingServer - You should have gotten this from Adobe when you started a subscription.
- s.trackingServerSecure (if tracking on https). You should have gotten this from Adobe when you started a subscription.

If you do not know any of the last 3, you need to contact Adobe Client Care to get that info, or you can follow the [directions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20644832/184595).

Comment: Thanks for the API link. I guess it is pretty open.  Even the trackingServer may fall back to 112.2o7.net if nothing is provided. The currencyCode defaults to "USD".  So ultimately, if you don't like the defaults then you need to set them.